# Changing to a project directory slows down the terminal on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ruby-on-rails

I am facing the inefficiency problem on the terminal. I have a ruby on rails project directory having a size of about 230 MB.
Whenever I perform any command in this directory such as cd etc. the terminal hangs for round about 5 minutes and then responds.
I have this problem on Ubuntu running on virtual vmware workstation.

Comment: Do you use any terminal enhancement packages or addons?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Can you please elaborate? I am using github account on terminal now.

Comment: Are there thousands of files in there?

Comment: no actually it contains default directories with some taking big size such as public folder takes 70 MB having audio video files etc.

Comment: My guess is you need to give your VM more RAM ... delay happens when the OS is thrashing ( frantically swapping RAM to and from disc ) ... kill that VM and create a new one with double the RAM allocated

Answer (score 0):

This question is not entirely clear. Problem is almost certainly not the "terminal" per se, but your virtual machine, the hardware where the VM host is running, the disk it is accessing, and/or your identity.

Your Ubuntu is an appliance in a Virtual Machine.  Are you logging in remotely to the Ubuntu VM? What OS is the virtual machine?  How powerful is the hardware? If your VM host is a Windoze computer, well, we have a suspect.  Where is the disk with the ruby material.  How is it partitioned, mounted, etc.

If you are only using one computer in this setup, and the disks are all local, and none are mounted through cross-platform adaptation (ext4 offered via cifs to Windows host, then offered back to Ubuntu VM as samba share), then we will know where to look.  In the Ubuntu vm session, make a new directory in the ~/home folder and fill it up with a few 100 MB of crap. If that is slow like your ruby disk, it will mean your VM host does not work well.

From your Ubuntu session, can we see output from "df" in the terminal?  Figure out where the ruby directory lies in that output.  That might be enough for us to get a guess.

Can you log into that VM host hardware directly in its native OS to interact with the problem directory?  Does it have slow interaction with the partition in question?

Off the wall, I can name 2 contexts where we have seen slowdowns like you describe.

1). Your user identity comes from a domain name server. The VM or your OS are asking for permission for your user to use a device over and over again, and not caching the answers.  It may be necessary to turn on nscd or similar caching of user identities.

2) Your hard disk holding the web code is not local to the VM and there's some software or hardware trouble between the two.

We see these nutty setups.  There is a Linux web server, which accesses a large storage device via NFS. That web server's directory is offered up to a Windows VM host as a samba share and the Host mounts the storage.  Then your Ubuntu client sees that Windows share mounted in the VM and says "ah, I'll use that windows share." So the VM host is translating the same stuff back and forth over. You'd be much better to mount the web file share directly in Ubuntu, rather than letting the Host be involved at all.

Recently, there was a flaky router between my system and a network file server that caused intermittent slow behavior that you describe.

Good luck, I think you won't get a good solution until you pin down the separate aspects of the problem and rule them out one at a time.